# Hide Node in Treeview List. in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-parsing, treeview

I am using VS 2005 C#, working on an unfinished WinForm.

I have parsed an XML to a treeview listing but I'm encountering some problems.
I wanna know if there's a way to hide/filter/remove a certain node containing a "_this_text" in its name without having to depend on a textbox.

This is what I have for the program (kudos to those who helped me develop this):

```
#region "***** XML Parsing *****"
    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the controls and the form.
        //label1.Text = "File Path";
        textBox2.Text = Application.StartupPath + "\\Continental.vsysvar";
        //button6.Text = "XML";
        //this.Text = "Software Validation";
    }

    private TreeNode selectedNode = null;

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // SECTION 1. Create a DOM Document and load the XML data into it.
            XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
            dom.Load(textBox2.Text);

            // SECTION 2. Initialize the TreeView control.
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            /*treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(dom.DocumentElement.Name));
            TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
            tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];*/

            foreach (XmlNode node in dom.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Name == "namespace" && node.ChildNodes.Count == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetAttributeText(node, "name")))
                    continue;
                AddNode(treeView1.Nodes, node);
            }

            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        /* catch (XmlException xmlEx)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(xmlEx.Message);
         }*/
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void LoadTreeFromXmlDocument(XmlDocument dom)
    {
        try
        {
            // SECTION 2. Initialize the TreeView control.
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

            // SECTION 3. Populate the TreeView with the DOM nodes.
            foreach (XmlNode node in dom.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Name == "namespace" && node.ChildNodes.Count == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetAttributeText(node, "name")))
                    continue;
                AddNode(treeView1.Nodes, node);
            }

            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static string GetAttributeText(XmlNode inXmlNode, string name)
    {
        XmlAttribute attr = (inXmlNode.Attributes == null ? null : inXmlNode.Attributes[name]);
        return attr == null ? null : attr.Value;
    }

    private void AddNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, XmlNode inXmlNode)
    {
        if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            string text = GetAttributeText(inXmlNode, "name");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                text = inXmlNode.Name;
            TreeNode newNode = nodes.Add(text);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
            for (int i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                XmlNode xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                AddNode(newNode.Nodes, xNode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If the node has an attribute "name", use that.  Otherwise display the entire text of the node.
            string text = GetAttributeText(inXmlNode, "name");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                text = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim();
            TreeNode newNode = nodes.Add(text);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

And here's an excerpt of the XMl file since it's quite long:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<systemvariables version="4">
  <namespace name="" comment="">
    <namespace name="_01_Test_Preparation" comment="">
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_02_Shipping_Status_Check" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_02_Shipping_Status_Check_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_01_Get_Dem_ID" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_01_Get_Dem_ID_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_04_ECU_Version_Check_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_03_Test_Run_Init" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_04_ECU_Version_Check" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_05_DEM_Reader" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_03_Test_Run_Init_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_01_05_DEM_Reader_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
    </namespace>
```

What I really want to accomplish is to hide or filter the nodes containing this text "_start" found in their name. So all nodes containing "_this_start" in their name would be hidden from the user. I've read that it is not technically possible to enable or disable visibility but instead gray out the text and whatnot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do they ever become visible again?  Or are they forever hidden?  Building a tree from XML should not be too expensive a process.  So unless it is massive, or changes frequently, I would consider rebuilding the entire tree each time, excluding the nodes that are to be "invisible".

Comment: It is supposed to be hidden from the user but cannot be actually removed from the xml file itself. I tried removing variables with "_start" included in its name and the external program just won't function properly. So variables having the same name with just that difference have same functions but cannot operate by itself, must be in pairs apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether the filter is static or can be configured by the user.  Assuming that the filter can be configured dynamically, what you could do is to (re)load the tree from the XML whenever the filter changes, recycling existing nodes, creating new nodes as needed, and deleting filtered nodes.  (Of course, this also works if the filter is static.)

First, extract a helper method to repopulate a tree from XML, recycling nodes by name when appropriate:

```
public delegate string GetString<T>(T input); // No Func<T, TResult> in c# 2.0

public static class XmlTreeViewHelper
{
    public static void AddOrMergeNodes(TreeNodeCollection treeNodeCollection, XmlNodeList xmlNodeList, GetString<XmlNode> getNodeName, GetString<XmlNode> getNodeText, Predicate<XmlNode> filter)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<TreeNode>> dict = ToNodeDictionary(treeNodeCollection);
        int index = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode inXmlNode in xmlNodeList)
        {
            AddOrMergeNode(treeNodeCollection, inXmlNode, ref index, getNodeName, getNodeText, filter, dict);
        }

        foreach (List<TreeNode> list in dict.Values)
            foreach (TreeNode leftover in list)
            {
                treeNodeCollection.Remove(leftover);
            }
    }

    static bool IsNodeAtIndex(TreeNodeCollection nodes, TreeNode node, int index)
    {
        // Avoid n-squared nodes.IndexOf(node).
        if (index < 0 || index >= nodes.Count)
            return false;
        return nodes[index] == node;
    }

    static void AddOrMergeNode(TreeNodeCollection treeNodeCollection, XmlNode inXmlNode, ref int index, GetString<XmlNode> getNodeName, GetString<XmlNode> getNodeText, Predicate<XmlNode> filter, Dictionary<string, List<TreeNode>> dict)
    {
        if (filter != null && !filter(inXmlNode))
            return;

        string treeName = getNodeName(inXmlNode);
        string treeText = (getNodeText == null ? treeName : getNodeText(inXmlNode));

        bool added = false;

        TreeNode treeNode;
        if (!DictionaryExtensions.TryRemoveFirst(dict, treeName, out treeNode))
        {
            treeNode = new TreeNode();
            treeNode.Name = treeName;
            treeNode.Text = treeText;
            added = true;
            treeNodeCollection.Insert(index, treeNode);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!IsNodeAtIndex(treeNodeCollection, treeNode, index))
            {
                treeNodeCollection.Remove(treeNode);
                treeNodeCollection.Insert(index, treeNode);
            }
        }

        index++;

        if (treeNode.Text != treeText)
            treeNode.Text = treeText;

        if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
            AddOrMergeNodes(treeNode.Nodes, inXmlNode.ChildNodes, getNodeName, getNodeText, filter);
        else
            treeNode.Nodes.Clear();

        if (added)
            treeNode.ExpandAll();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a dictionary of tree nodes by node name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nodes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static Dictionary<string, List<TreeNode>> ToNodeDictionary(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<TreeNode>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<TreeNode>>();
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            DictionaryExtensions.Add(dict, node.Name, node);
        return dict;
    }
}

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Add<TKey, TValueList, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValueList> listDictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
        where TValueList : IList<TValue>, new()
    {
        if (listDictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        TValueList values;
        if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out values))
            listDictionary[key] = values = new TValueList();
        values.Add(value);
    }

    public static bool TryGetValue<TKey, TValueList, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValueList> listDictionary, TKey key, int index, out TValue value)
        where TValueList : IList<TValue>
    {
        TValueList list;
        if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
            return Returns.False(out value);
        if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
            return Returns.False(out value);
        value = list[index];
        return true;
    }

    public static bool TryRemoveFirst<TKey, TValueList, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValueList> listDictionary, TKey key, out TValue value)
        where TValueList : IList<TValue>
    {
        TValueList list;
        if (!listDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
            return Returns.False(out value);
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            value = list[0];
            list.RemoveAt(0);
            if (--count == 0)
                listDictionary.Remove(key);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            listDictionary.Remove(key); // Error?
            return Returns.False(out value);
        }
    }
}

public static class Returns
{
    public static bool False<TValue>(out TValue value)
    {
        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Next, dynamically (re)load the XML and apply whatever filter is appropriate:

```
    private void ReloadTreeFromXmlDocument(XmlDocument dom)
    {
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            XmlTreeViewHelper.AddOrMergeNodes(treeView1.Nodes, dom.DocumentElement.ChildNodes, GetTreeNodeName, GetTreeNodeText, FilterNode);
        }
        finally
        {
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
        }
    }

    static string GetTreeNodeName(XmlNode inXmlNode)
    {
        string text = GetAttributeText(inXmlNode, "name");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            text = inXmlNode.Name;
        return text;
    }

    static string GetTreeNodeText(XmlNode inXmlNode)
    {
        string text = GetAttributeText(inXmlNode, "name");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                text = inXmlNode.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                text = (inXmlNode.OuterXml).Trim();
            }
        }
        return text;
    }

    string filter = "_start"; // Reload when this changes

    bool FilterNode(XmlNode inXmlNode)
    {
        return FilterNode(inXmlNode, filter /*filterComboBox.Text*/);
    }

    bool FilterNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, string nodeNameFilter)
    {
        if (inXmlNode.Name == "namespace" && inXmlNode.ChildNodes.Count == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetAttributeText(inXmlNode, "name")))
            return false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeNameFilter))
        {
            string text = GetTreeNodeText(inXmlNode);
            if (text.Contains(nodeNameFilter))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static string GetAttributeText(XmlNode inXmlNode, string name)
    {
        XmlAttribute attr = (inXmlNode.Attributes == null ? null : inXmlNode.Attributes[name]);
        return attr == null ? null : attr.Value;
    }
```

After backporting my solution to .Net 2.0, this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: do i have to include other namespaces for this aside from system.xml? and also, version i'm using is old so other types cannot be recognized by VS.

Comment: @Kurisuchin - I removed use of the `Linq` namespace and all uses of the `var` keyword, so I believe this should be c#-2.0 clean.

Comment: I think .TryRemoveFirst isn't also compatible with c#2.0. I'm very sorry about this, tried to request to grant me a newer version. Rejected.

Comment: Do you have anything to replace this with? `(!dict.TryRemoveFirst(treeName, out treeNode))`
My colleague did a bit of editing with the code you provided but to compensate for the TryRemoveFirst but no luck.

Comment: Nothing's happening, actually. Maybe I did something wrong here.

Comment: @Kurisuchin - you mean nothing is showing, or the filter isn't being applied?  I notice that your `button6_Click()` doesn't actually call `LoadTreeFromXmlDocument()` (which I renamed to `ReloadTreeFromXmlDocument()`), maybe that's the confusion?

Comment: Filtering is not happening. Probably, that's it?

Comment: Could be.  Suggest merging `button6_Click()` and `LoadTreeFromXmlDocument()` so you don't have duplicated routines.

Comment: It worked on the first few nodes and childnodes, but when I scrolled all the way down on the list, apparently, it didn't work throughout the entire list. Is there perhaps a limit on this?
EDIT: It actually duplicated itself, so filtering worked for the entire lost but it also copied itself. I'll check again.

Comment: @Kurisuchin - shouldn't be.  Can you show the entire XML that causes the problem or upload to a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: @Kurisuchin - can you update your question to show the code that shows the duplicating behavior?

Comment: I know where I went wrong. I duplicated the `AddNode` (section 3) snippet. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this also doable to ListView?

Comment: hello hi! to update, everything's working well. tbh, the delegate and dictionary stuff are not really familiar to me. COuld you perhaps explain such to me? Even though I get some parts of the code, but as a whole, it's all quite confusing to me.