# Display xml tags and values in treeview winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to display xml data using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438168/5859562
but the problem is that the query only selects only tag names and I want values aswell. The query is as follows:

```
element.HasElements ?
    node.AddRange(from item in element.Elements()
    let tree = new TreeNode(item.Name.LocalName)
    from newNode in GetNodes(tree, item)
    select newNode)
    : new[] { node };
```

So far I managed to come up with something that's almost working, I added

```
let tree = item.HasElements ? new TreeNode(item.Name.LocalName) :
        new TreeNode(item.Value)
```

so now if it's the "most inner" tag it shows the value (the perfect solution will show the tag name and then the value).

Say for this xml I'd like the data to be displayed like this:

```
<StepList>
  <Step1>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Empty>void1</Empty>
  </Step1>
  <Step2>
    <Name>Name2</Name>
    <Empty>void2</Empty>
  </Step2>
</StepList>
```

[image: Example picture]

Comment: You want something like this?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317597   If you need to merge changes after modifying the underlying XML, see [Hide Node in Treeview List. in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28711092/3744182).

Comment: Well, I pretty much copy - pasted the code from that microsoft link and deleted controls i didnt need... aaand it works like a charm. Thanks.